# using css z-index to make loader appear at highest level

Tags: css, vue.js

I am trying to make my loader appear at the highest level so that it overlaps on top of the items in the list--instead of remain on top of it. For instance, if I increase the size- it pushes the list of items down instead of not interfere with them at all. I added a z-index, but no help.

```css
ul{
z-index:10;
}

#loader {
                border: 20px solid orange;
                border-top: 20px solid;
                border-radius: 50%;
                width: 70px;
                height: 70px;
                animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
                margin: auto;
                z-index:100px;
            }

            @keyframes spin {
                0% {
                    transform: rotate(0deg);
                }

                100% {
                    transform: rotate(360deg);
                }
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
<div id="loader"></div>
<ul>
<li>addsassadsdsadsadsaasdddaadsadadsdsadsadasdadsadaddsadsadsdsadsasadas</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The you have to position the loader accordingly `absolute` perhaps?

Comment: yes thats what i was missing- thanks

Comment: https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/wvjwzKw

Comment: `z-index` doesn't take a unit. You have `100px`, it should just be `z-index: 100`.